# "Too much" before adjectives

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, dictionaries

> You use **much too** in front of an adjective to say that something cannot
> be done or achieved because someone or something has too much of a
> quality.  In sentences like these you put **much** in front of *too*, not after
> it:
>
> *The bedrooms were **(much) too** cold.*
>
> In positive sentences, don't use **much** without *very*. Don't say, for example, ‘I enjoyed it **much**’ or ‘We **much** agree’
>
> https://www.wordreference.com/EnglishUsage/much

However, the OALD offers examples such as [I am **very much aware** of the fact that I'm **not much good** at tennis.](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/much_1?q=much)

Aren't the two authorities contradictory?

Comment: "Much" is a special word. It can almost never be used without a modifier, and it accepts a wide variety of modifiers, including negative words like "not" and "never".

Answer (score 1):

These are not contradictory. The rule given by word reference is "In positive sentences, don't use much without very"

**Very much** is an idiom - think of it as a separate word with its own usage rules. There are places where you can use [very much](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/very%20much) where *much* alone would be ungrammatical.

*I'm not much good at tennis.* is a sentence with **negative polarity**, due to the use of *not*. As this is not a positive sentence, the rule doesn't apply. "I enjoyed it much" is ungrammatical, but "I didn't enjoy it much" is grammatical.

Comment: "Are you busy? -Not **very** (_much_?)"   https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Talk:very#Are_you_busy?_-Not_very.

Answer (score 0):

No. They are not in conflict.

The main clause in your second example is positive. You can grammatically say

> am very aware that …

or

> am very much aware

but

> am much aware

is so rare as to be unidiomatic. See

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=am+very+aware%2C+am+very+much+aware%2C+am+much+aware&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cam%20very%20aware%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cam%20very%20much%20aware%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cam%20much%20aware%3B%2Cc0

The subordinate clause in your second example is negative as shown by “not.”

I also point out that the first authority is talking about the phrase “much too” in what are technically positive clauses, a topic not covered by the second authority.

Comment: Is **much aware** grammatical?  -->  "Grammar Point: Very is used with adjectives, past participles used as adjectives, and adverbs, but notice this use: 
_I’m very much afraid that..._" https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/very_1?q=very

Comment: The reason I gave the citation to ngram was to show that phrases like “am much aware” are not totally **unknown** but are so rare that they may possibly be ungrammatical and are probably unidiomatic. It is impossible to make more than a few hard and fast rules that apply to every dialectical variant of English.